# python2.7.8: TypeError: expected string or buffer with bs4 and re

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am unable to figure out why I am getting this error. I am following [this tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/remove-html-tags-python) to extract actual text. But I don’t understand the error.

Could someone have a look at my code?

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)" # link of website
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read() # reading and opening link
soup = BeautifulSoup(html) #parsing


for script in soup(["script", "style","a","<div id=\"bottom\" >"]): # all tags
    script.extract()    # clear out


for p in soup.find_all('p'): # loop for printing text
    r = re.sub("<.*?>", "", p) # expression to get rid from <p> <b> etc
    print r
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/python/s/fyp/textextractioon.py", line 16, in <module>
    r = re.sub("<.*?>", "", p)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 151, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your final loop to :

```
for p in soup.find_all('p'): # loop for printing text
    r = re.sub("<.*?>", "", p.text) # expression to get rid from <p> <b> etc
    print r
```

every p is from type class 'bs4.element.Tag':
and it has some built in methods, take a look so it would be clear for you

Comment: one thing more i am not getting those words which are on url link for example in wikipedia python text is marked as hyper link. so any idea where i am doing wrong?

Comment: i did not understand the q